# Do we still need the sproutcore-2 tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Most recent questions tagged [sproutcore-2](/questions/tagged/sproutcore-2) are also tagged [emberjs](/questions/tagged/emberjs). Both tag wikis point out that the project originally known as Sproutcore 2 is now Ember.js. It seems likely that there will eventually be a Sproutcore 2 (that is, the project still known as Sproutcore, spawned from the Sproutcore 1.x series, will have a version 2) and that will be different from what is now Ember.js. What's the proper fate of the sproutcore-2 tag?

Comment: Not true; there are 37 questions tagged [tag:sproutcore-2] and [tag:emberjs] but 51 questions tagged [tag:sproutcore-2]. Anyway, duly untagging obvious cases.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451117/firebug-is-showing-error-in-the-controller-sproutcore-2) appears to be only about Sproutcore 2.

Comment: Interesting. That changes the character of the question, then. Thanks for looking in to this, I'll update the question.